# Как получить логарифм по заданному основанию для списка?

Tags: python, numpy, список

Как записать математическое выражение в питоне, выдается ошибка. Нужно чтобы log(...) по основанию 1+x**2, для различных `x`.

```py
import numpy as np

x = [1, 10, 100, 1000]
print("Входные значения x: \n", x)
y = np.log(1 / np.e ** np.sin(x + 1) / (5 / 4) + (1 / x ** 15)) / np.log(1 + x ** 2)
print(y)
```

Получаю ошибку:

> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

Comment: Какую задачу вы решаете? Какую ошибку получаете?

Comment: Ошибка: TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list, Задача: Записать выражение и получить его значение в заданных точках x

Comment: Выражение: log(1 / np.e ** np.sin(x + 1) / (5 / 4) + (1 / x ** 15), основание логарифма (1+х**2)

Comment: `x` - у вас список. А вы пишите `x + 1`.

Comment: А как записать, если нужно посчитать для нескольких Х-ов?

Comment: `y = [np.log(1 / np.e ** np.sin(i + 1) / (5 / 4) + (1 / i ** 15)) / np.log(1 + i ** 2) for i in x]`

Comment: Спасибо, помогли

Comment: @GrAnd формально к вопросу нет никаких претензий. Я вам предлагаю оформить свой комментарий как ответ, чтобы вопрос мог быть закрыт ответом.

Comment: `x = np.array(x)` - список надо преобразовать в массив. Тогда ваше выражение будет работать нормально.

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка в выражении `x + 1`:

> ```
> $ python
> Python 3.10.0 (default, Oct 16 2021, 12:17:56) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> @>>> x = [1, 10, 100, 1000]
> @>>> x + 1
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
> ```

Исправить можно переведя список в массив numpy:

> ```
> @>>> import numpy as np
> @>>> x = np.array(x)
> @>>> x + 1
> array([   2,   11,  101, 1001])
> ```

Целиком исправленная программа:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 10, 100, 1000])
print("Входные значения x: \n", x)
y = np.log(1 / np.e ** np.sin(x + 1) / (5 / 4) + (1 / x ** 15)) / np.log(1 + x ** 2)
print(y)
```

Comment: Это самый правильный вариант, пусть векторно всё считается, раз уж `numpy` в деле

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант через *math*

```
import math

x = [1, 10, 100, 1000]

print("Входные значения x: \n", x)

def logs(x1):
    base = (1 + x1 ** 2)
    ex = 1 / math.e ** math.sin(x1 + 1) / (5 / 4) + (1 / x1 ** 15)
    return math.log(ex, base)

print([logs(i) for i in x])

>>> [0.40299028466113235, 0.16832640716567754, -0.0733047836576131, -0.08274280283465775]
```

Comment: Тогда везде поменяйте `np.` на `math.`

Comment: А в чём различие np от math ?

Comment: math — это стандартная библиотека, предоставляющая ряд функций и константы.

numpy — это библиотека, написанная на C. Основным объектом numpy является однородный многомерный массив ndarray.

Этот массив позволяет выполнять математические операции над всем массивом (или столбцами, строками), не зацикливаясь на элементах. 

numpy очень мощный и невероятно быстрый + это основа библиотеки анализа данных pandas. (но не всегда - операции с большими числами (не массивами) в math будут проходить быстрее)